# ''bundletool'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, android, app, apk

Estoy intentando convertir un archivo .aab a .apk con el siguiente comando:

```
bundletool build-apks –bundle=aplicacion.aab –output=aplicacion.apks –mode=universal
```

y me sale que no lo reconoce en la cmd.

Previamente me he descargado el bundletool.jar del repositorio de github., hay alguna forma de ejecutar dicho archivo o como podría ejecutar el comando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reconoce el comando ya que no encuentra el archivo a ejecuta, por esta razón recibes el mensaje:

> 'bundletool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

Para usar la utilería `bundletool` primeramente se descarga el .jar de BundleTool desde:

https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases

para usar la utilería `bundletool` es sencillo, te preguntaras como ejecutar el archivo .jar que descargaste, pues para esto puedes hacer uso de el comando `java` :

```
java -jar bundletool.jar argumentos
```

por ejemplo:

```
java -jar <path archivo bundletool.jar> build-apks --bundle=<path archivo .aab> --output=<path archivo .apks> –-mode=universal
```

Las opciones deben iniciar con -- (no con -), la salida del archivo creado a partir del archivo `.aab` sería `.apks`.

[image: Jorgesys build tool]